# Live streaming from UWP to Linux/Python Server

Tags: linux, sockets, video, uwp, streaming

I have an UWP app that capture a live video stream (webcam), encodes it in h264, and sends it through a TCP socket (in a local network, I need high performance) to a Linux device.

Is there a way to do this? I need the video not for playing it but for extract single frames. I could do that with opencv but it requires a local video file, instead I'm using a live stream.

I would send photos instead of a video stream if the time needed for capture one was acceptable, but it requires about 250 ms.

Is RTP required? Does UWP (windows) provides a way to achive this?

Thank you

P.S.: The UWP app runs in Hololens.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC to transmit live video from the HoloLens easily to any target. That's probably the easiest way to do it without going really low level.

For an introduction just grab this repo and try the sample app which runs perfectly on the HoloLens https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/PeerCC/tree/e95f231e1dc9c248ca2ffa040276b8a1265da145/Client

Comment: I tried but WebRTC, beacuse of is suited for global network connections, is very slow (adding a lot of unnecessary work in my case). I need performance so I need to go low level but I can't find out any solution.